# How to handle the zero deviation with Wilcoxon test and t-test(with zero standard deviation data)

Tags: r, t-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am a newbie of statistics

I am looking for a statistical test for **zero standard deviation data** VS **a distributed data**

Here is the example:

```
ddd2

      name   srmse_avg           method
459  arone 8.587927  ARMA    1 proposed
468  arone 8.952136  ARMA    2 proposed
477  arone 8.443238  ARMA    3 proposed
486  arone 8.096387  ARMA    4 proposed
495  arone 8.644613  ARMA    5 proposed

1359 arone 9.515574  ARMA    1 baseline
1368 arone 9.515574  ARMA    2 baseline
1377 arone 9.515574  ARMA    3 baseline
1386 arone 9.515574  ARMA    4 baseline
1395 arone 9.515574  ARMA    5 baseline
```

Actually, I did the Wilcoxon test in r, and Here is the result

```
> test <- wilcox.test(ddd2$srmse_avg ~ ddd2$method, alternative = "greater")
Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(x = c(9.51557350975475, 9.51557350975475,  :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
> test

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  ddd2$rmse_avg by ddd2$method
W = 100, p-value = 3.193e-05
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is greater than 0
```

So I am not sure that I can trust this result

1. Did I do this correctly? because the baseline method has zero standard deviation
2. Is there any statistical test method for this kind of dataset?
3. Is there any way for avoiding the warning message?

Thank you so much!!

---

I just realized that this is a problem of non-parametric problem for one sample t-test
like Wilcoxon signed rank sum test or sign test...

Please let me know if this is wrong..

Answer (score 1):

- The warning from the *wilcox.test()* function just means what it says:  the function cannot compute the *exact* *p*-value when there are ties.  So it computes an asymptotic *p*-value using an approximation.  This is fine.  By default, the function applies a continuity correction, which is helpful with the smaller sample size.
- It does appear that you are right that what you really want is a one-sample test.  As you mention, the one-sample Wilcoxon signed rank test or one-sample sign test would be options. You could also use a permutation test.  The choice of test depends on the exact hypothesis you wish to test.

Answer (score 0):

Let $H_0$ be the null hypothesis that the (population) standard deviation is zero

You can have a test that rejects this null when the observations are not all the same. This has zero Type I error rate: if the population standard deviation is zero, the observations are all the same with probability 1.  It has 100% power against any continuous distribution with non-zero standard deviation and pretty good power against discrete distributions.

You do need a criterion for when two observations are the same, which will depend on your measurement methods.